# how to import class of another package from different project in AIDL file?

Tags: android, aidl

I have a AIDL file that implemented in the package under ProjectA, and I am trying to import a Parcelable class (Foo) from another package under ProjectB. Below is the way how I implemented the MyService.AIDL file:

```
package com.packageA.projectA
import com.packageB.projectB.Foo

interface MyService{

void getSomething(Foo foo); 
}
```

However, I get this compilation error "couldn't find import for class com.example.projectB.Foo". If I copied the packageB to packageA, then I will get no compilation error.

Is there a way to import parcelable class from package under different project? I know there're multiple questions on stackoverflow and elsewhere (like google group) about importing parcelable under the same project, but none from different projects. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say that you defined the class for the parcelable class and you are not able to use that class in the aidl ?
Try the below solution.
you have your MyService.AIDL in your src/xxx path.
Now create Foo.aidl (name should be same)in the same path and define that Foo.aidl as below.

```
package com.packageB.projectB
parcelable Foo
```

now remove the import statement from MyService.AIDL and re-type it (its for refreshing , else it will show same error)
now that import error must be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had the same problem and found the solution very ugly.

I had two classes defined in the package:

com.lni.codephg.inter

I had another class defined in the package

com.pcha.androidbtmanager

The actual AIDL interfaces were defined in the package

com.pcha.proprietary.handler

The client would be looking for remote services implementing methods in the package com.pcha.proprietary.handler.

So what did my AIDL file hierarchy have to look like to make this work?

```
src\main\aidl\com\lni\codephg\inter
    MetricIntermediary.aidl
    MdsIntermediary.aidl
src\main\aidl\com\pcha\androidbtmanager
    PhdInformation.aidl
src\main\aidl\com\pcha\proprietary\handler
    IConnectionCallback.aidl
    IIntermediaryCallback.aidl
    IProprietaryDeviceHandler.aidl
    IStatusEventCallback.aidl
```

The 'one-liner' files defining the custom classes like MdsIntermediary.aidl look like this

```
// MdsIntermediary.aidl
package com.lni.codephg.inter;

   parcelable MetricIntermediary;
```

I have to admit I do understand why these one-liner files must exist in such a weird form.

Then the interface AIDL files that reference them (for example IIntermediaryCallback.aidl) look like this

```
// IIntermediaryCallback.aidl
package com.pcha.proprietary.handler;

// Declare any non-default types here with import statements
import com.lni.codephg.inter.MdsIntermediary;
import com.lni.codephg.inter.MetricIntermediary;

interface IIntermediaryCallback
{
    void onMdsIntermediary(in MdsIntermediary mds);
    void onReceiveMetricIntermediaries (in List<MetricIntermediary> metricList, in 
          MdsIntermediary mds);
}
```

Of course I had to implement the Parcelable methods on the said custom classes. However, as ugly as that was, Android Studio seemed to do it for me. Since I know nothing about Parcelable I don't know if it is good enough or if I have to do some massaging.

This was painfully difficult. Hope this will save someone hours of frustration.